# How do I initialize a private static readonly HashSet<char>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want a private, constant member

```
private static readonly HashSet<char> _nameChars
```

in my controller, containing the characters `' ', 'a', 'A', ..., 'z', 'Z'`. The purpose is for server-side validation of a form. But how do I initialize that `HashSet`?

```
private static readonly HashSet<char> _nameChars = ?????
```

Is there a good way of doing that? I know that C++ has bracket initialization for `std::set`.

Comment: If the initialization is more complicated, you can use a static constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# also has collection initializers:

```
 private static readonly HashSet<char> _nameChars = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'b', ...};
```

You might also use a constructor that takes `IEnumerable<T>` argument:

```
private static readonly HashSet<char> _nameChars = new HashSet<char>("abcde...");
```

I find the 2nd approach more readable.

Comment: The collection initializer uses a loop to initialize the `HashSet<T>`, the constructor does the same. But i would also prefer the second because it's easier to maintain.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Right, nothing to optimize there for a `string` parameter. It is faster for an `ICollection<T>` parameter, as the HashSet's capacity can be initialized to ICollection<T>.Count.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:

```
static IReadOnlyCollection<char> ExcludedFields = new HashSet<char> {
        'a', 'b', ...
};
```